# Can I enter elements in an array with the help of for-each loop in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

When i tried to enter values with help of for each loop , it ran fine and it ran for 3 times i.e the size of my array but when i printed values of array elements is prints the default value i.e 0 . Someone explain why this happens. Why can't I enter values in array with help of for each loop.

the code is :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class JavaArrays {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int marks[] = new int[3];

   for(int ele: marks){
       ele = sc.nextInt();
   }

    for (int ele : marks){
        System.out.print(ele+" ");
    }

}
```

}

the output is :

```
//. 23 45 100 -> values i entered
//. 0 0 0 -> values that got printed
```

Please tell my why for each loop is not being able to enter values in the array? I expected output to be 23 45 100

Comment: "*Can I enter elements in an array with the help of for-each loop in Java?*" - No.

Comment: A for each loop over an array is equivalent to a basic for loop over the indices; it just hides the index. You should just use a basic for loop if you need access to the index.

Answer (score 1):

You can't update array's element using `for-each`. This is only for reading.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] marks = new int[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < marks.length; i++)
        marks[i] = sc.nextInt();

    for (int ele : marks)
        System.out.print(ele + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your first for-loop.  You are assigning *nextInt* to *ele*.
Rather, the *marks* array is what you need to assign *ele* to.

```java
for (int ele : marks) {
    ele = sc.nextInt();
}
```

Instead of a loop, you can just assign the 3 values to their indices.

```java
marks[0] = sc.nextInt();
marks[1] = sc.nextInt();
marks[2] = sc.nextInt();
```